# Interface CSP over UART on PIC 24FJ256GA110 with no operating system

Tags: cubesat

I am using a PIC 24FJ256GA110 without an operating system. Is there any reference code I can use as a starting point to write the driver for the GOMSpace transceiver?

Also if someone has advice on how to do this it would be greatly appreciated as I am fairly new to the CSP.

Comment: An operating system is not necessary to use an UART as interface. For first tests using a terminal program on a PC is very helpful to see the output of the USART. For a successful communication, baud rate, number of data bits, number of stop bits and parity bit must match precisely.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because writing drivers, isn't about space exploration, *just* because they're for space hardware

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! It looks like your question will be closed soon. While there are certainly on-topic questions here related to software, some people don't feel this is sufficiently related to space exploration. If you are not aware of it yet, there is a site called [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) where this might be better asked. Alternately, once closed, if you can edit the question and change it from "how to write an OS" to something more like "how to search for or which cubesat projects might have included custom software written for this GOMSpace product?"...

Comment: ...then the question may be reopened. Not everyone has figured out yet that *question-closing is not a sport*, and adding a helpful comment is really the right way to greet new users.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments. I will change the wording of this question and also post it to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @J.Allam three more things: 1) use the `@` function in front of a user's name; that way they will receive a notification that you have replied. I found your comment here just now by accident. 2) It's fairly strongly discouraged to ask the same question on two different sites, so make sure that your edit here is different than your question in SO. And 3) just a caution, SO is nicer than it used to be but you may find asking there more challenging because it is very active. Once you post there, keep an eye on your question and respond to the nice/helpful comments quickly. Just a thought!

Comment: @J.Allam the Electrical Engineering stack exchange is probably the better place to post your question.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I didn't realize that existed either.